# Behavior of cv2.VideoCapture.grab & retrieve under threading

Tags: python-multithreading, opencv, python

I have some simple code using a thread to grab frames from a public rtsp stream and then retrieve it for processing. I am getting a strange behavior for the first frame.

The output from the print statements are shown below. It seems to be looping VideoCapture.retrieve twice before moving on. Is this normal?

```
 0 False
 0 True
 0 (160, 240, 3)
 1 True
 1 (160, 240, 3)
 2 True
 2 (160, 240, 3)
```

I am running Python 3.7 on Windows 10.

```
from threading import Thread
import cv2, time

video_source=r'rtsp://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov'

class VideoStreamWidget(object):

    def __init__(self, src):
        
        self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(src)
        # Start the thread to read frames from the video stream
        self.thread = Thread(target=self.update, args=(), daemon=True)
        self.thread.start()
        
    def update(self):
        # Read the next frame from the stream in a different thread
        while True:
            if self.capture.isOpened():
                self.capture.grab()
            time.sleep(.01)
   
    def retrieve_frame(self, n):

        (self.status, self.frame)=self.capture.retrieve()
        print(n, self.status)
        print(n, self.frame.shape)
        
if __name__ == '__main__':

    video_stream_widget = VideoStreamWidget(video_source)
    
    n=0
    while True:
        try:
            video_stream_widget.retrieve_frame(n)
            n +=1
        except AttributeError:
            pass
```